# IllegalStateException at bundle update

Tags: android, google-play, adobecreativesdk

I have a curious anomaly that the Play Console pointed out. I see a high number of crashes after I started to roll out a new app version.

In the new app version I removed the `Adobe Creative SDK` library.
The app crashes – if I understand it correctly – when the previous version is going to be updated. Ironically, the crash is caused by the Adobe Creative SDK library.

The crash stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3705)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1979)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1701)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1657)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:644)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:644)
+> at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsReceiver.handlePackageReplaced (CdsReceiver.java:123)
|  at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsReceiver.onReceive (CdsReceiver.java:103)
|  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3695)
|
+––– this causes the crash
```

Is there any way I can fix a crash like that, before I go to full rollout?

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it on the test device that I have.

Also it just seems to happen for Android 8.0 and 8.1.

Any help is highly appreciated! If you want to see anything more, tell me and I add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old version of the app crashes when the app is going to be replaced I wouldn't worry too much about it. The app was going to be stopped during replacement anyway. I suspect the developers of the Creative SDK have a bug in their code because they assumed their package was never going to be removed. The only was to fix it would be to encourage then Adobe Developers to fix it, and I suspect they are unlikely to fix a bug that makes it easier to migrate away from their product.